# создать класс после проверки в if C#

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Есть задача в том чтобы проверить у пользователя серийник и выдать ему соответствующий уровень доступа ( Basic , Pro , Expert ) Pro, Expert наследники от Basic
Но как создать обьект класса после проверки if, так как если создавать в if , выходя с цикла уже не будет этого обьекта

```
int keyForPro = 12345;
        int keyForExp = 54321;
        Console.WriteLine("Введите серийный ключ.");
        int check = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (check == keyForPro)
        {
            var userAcess = new DocumentWorker();
        }
        if (check == keyForExp)
        {
            var userAcess = new ProDocumentWorker();
        }
        else
        {
            var userAcess = new ExpertDocumentWorker();
            
        }

        userAcess.PrintInfo(); // уже не работает , каким способом можно после этой проверки создавать обьект класса чтобы он дальше существовал ?
```

Comment: Создать переменную вне `if`, а инициализировать в `if`???

Comment: @ПавелЕриков не работает, создаю вне if ProDocumentWorker user1;
в цикле user1 = new ProDocumentWorker();
                user1.OpenDocument(); - всё работает
вне цикла  user1.OpenDocument(); - не работает :)

Comment: Ну так у вас `Basic` родительский класс, его и создавайте, а не `ProDocumentWorker`

Comment: всё работает, понял спасибо )

Answer (score 1):

```
int keyForPro = 12345;
int keyForExp = 54321;
Console.WriteLine("Введите серийный ключ.");
int check = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
DocumentWorker user1;

if (check == keyForPro)
{
    user1 = new ProDocumentWorker();
}
else if (check == keyForExp)
{
    user1 = new ExpertDocumentWorker();
}
else
{
    user1 = new DocumentWorker();
}

user1.OpenDocument();
```